# How to split one field in two and submit as one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have Full name in my form as one input box but I want to make it split in two input boxes

1. box1= First Name
2. box2= Last Name

and when submit button is pressed, the value is saved as box1+box2 in the same old full name data scheme in my mysql database.

Here is my current code.

```
<td colspan="2"><span class="smalltext"><label for="username">{$lang->username}</label></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" class="textbox" name="username" id="username" style="width: 100%" value="" /></td>
</tr>
```

and here is full page code

````
<form action="member.php" method="post" id="registration_form"><input type="text" style="visibility: hidden;" value="" name="regcheck1" /><input type="text" style="visibility: hidden;" value="true" name="regcheck2" />
{$regerrors}
<table border="0" cellspacing="{$theme['borderwidth']}" cellpadding="{$theme['tablespace']}" class="tborder">
<tr>
<td class="thead" colspan="2"><strong>{$lang->registration}</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%" class="trow1" valign="top">
<fieldset class="trow2">
<legend><strong>{$lang->account_details}</strong></legend>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="{$theme['tablespace']}" width="100%">
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><span class="smalltext"><label for="fullname">{$lang->fullname}</label></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" class="textbox" name="fullname" id="fullname" style="width: 100%" value="fullname" /></td>
</tr>
{$passboxes}
<tr>
<td><span class="smalltext"><label for="email">{$lang->email}</label></span></td>
<td><span class="smalltext"><label for="email2">{$lang->confirm_email}</label></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="textbox" name="email" id="email" style="width: 100%" maxlength="50" value="{$email}" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="textbox" name="email2" id="email2" style="width: 100%" maxlength="50" value="{$email2}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="display: none;" id="email_status">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
{$hiddencaptcha}
</table>
</fieldset>






<div align="center">
<input type="hidden" name="step" value="registration" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="do_register" />
<input type="submit" class="button" name="regsubmit" value="{$lang->submit_registration}" />
</div>
</form>```
````

Comment: How are you saving that in your database ?

Comment: Can you get the value in php side and concatenate them?

Comment: Let me upload the full form Dear LSE and BETOMBO

Comment: I have edited the questions Dear @LSE and Dear @ BETOMBO

Comment: Thanks ! Like BETOMBO said, can't you concatenate those two values inside member.php ?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the values in your php file and store them in your database column.
I can explain it more in detail if you share your php file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you a frontend solution (because of the tags attached to the question), which could work if:

- You just need a quick fix
- This is a one-time problem
- You know that this won't create complications in the future

Other than that, I highly recommend you do this in the backend.

The idea here is to create a hidden `fullname` input and use javascript to concatenate the first and last name.

```js
const name = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: ''
}

document.querySelector('[name="firstName"]').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  name.firstName = e.target.value
  updateFullName()
})

document.querySelector('[name="lastName"]').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  name.lastName = e.target.value
  updateFullName()
})

function updateFullName() {
  document.querySelector('[name="fullname"]').value = `${name.firstName} ${name.lastName}`
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstName">
  <input type="text" name="lastName">
  <input type="hidden" name="fullname">
</form>
```